# Count once entries of 3 categories specified in another column in R

Tags: r, count

This might be very trivial but I could not find an easy solution anywhere. I am trying to create a script in R to count entries in one column that belong to a one of 3 categories specified another column. I have a list of clinical patients with ID numbers (more than one entry for the same ID) that have been seen by two services (a or b). I need to know how many ID have been seen by service a and by service b and service c, but counting repeated visits by a service only once (so basically the number of patients that have used each service at least once) - hope this makes sense, here is an example to explain.

Example:

```
     ID    Category
     A001  a
     A002  a 
     A002  a
     A002  b
     A003  b
     A003  b
     A005  c
     A001  a
     A004  b
     A004  b
     A006  c
     A006  a
```

Output should be something like:

```
     a=3
     b=3
     c=2
```

This is what I have done, but I am quite stuck, and this might not be good at all!

```
 DataString<- matrix(nrow=dim(refnum)[1], ncol=1)
 for (i in 1:dim(refnum)[1]){
   DataString[i,1]<- paste(refnum[i,], collapse = '')
 }

 #generate vector of unique strings
 uniqueID<- unique(DataString)

 #create new matrix to store new IDs
 newID<- matrix(nrow=dim(data)[1], ncol=1)

 #initiate index n
 n<-0
 #loop through unique strings
 for (i in 1:dim(refnum)[1]){
   #increment n by 1 for each increment through unique strings
   n<- n+1
   #loop through data rows
   for (j in 1:dim(data)[1]){    
     #find matches with string i
     index<- which(DataString == uniqueID[i,1])
     #assign new ID to matching rows
     newID[index,1]<- n
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your question preamble mentions "*that have been seen by two services (a or b)*" but there are three "services" in your "Category" column. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the many solutions:

```
table(df[!duplicated(df), "Category"])

# a b c 
# 3 3 2
```

Comment: +1 I was *just* about to post `table(unique(mydf)$Category)`, but wasn't sure that I've fully read the question correctly.

Comment: ah, that's even better! `unique` skipped my mind. Care to make that an answer?

Comment: done. I was hesitant to do so because it is conceptually very similar your answer.

Comment: I just realised that the `do.call` is not necessary.

Comment: Made it work. Just had to make sure the df was actually a data frame and not a matrix. However the table(unique(df)$category) Many thanks,

Comment: I'm glad it worked @Marco. If this answered your question, please mark it as such by ticking it underneath the score.

Comment: It worked!!! Just had to make sure the df was actually a data frame and not a matrix. However the table(unique(df)$category) command gave me the error "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" but the first command worked well. Many, many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If my interpretation of the question so far is correct, you might be able to use the following:

```
table(unique(mydf)$Category)
# 
# a b c 
# 3 3 2
```

I'm a little bit cautious, though, because of your sentence *"so basically the number of patients that have used each service at least once"*, which sounds like you want patients who have availed all three services, in which case the answer is none!

As such, `aggregate` might also be of interest, to at least see more easily what you're dealing with:

```
temp <- aggregate(Category ~ ID, mydf, function(x) sort(unique(x)))
temp
#     ID Category
# 1 A001        a
# 2 A002     a, b
# 3 A003        b
# 4 A004        b
# 5 A005        c
# 6 A006     a, c
```

A possible advantage here is that the earlier tabulation (if it is what you need) is also possible from the output of `aggregate` by using `table(unlist(temp$Category))`, so you get to see both utilization of services by ID and whatever summary you need.